# Не сработало событие On Click Jquery

Tags: jquery

```
$(function() {
    $('body').on('click', '.extendWrapper .item', function(){
    alert('Hello');
    });
});
```

Какие есть мысли по этому поводу?

Comment: на будущее, кидайте пример воспроизводящий ошибку на http://jsfiddle.net  
если повторить там не удастся, значит ошибка не там, смотрите консоль, отладчик и т.д.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on('click', '.extendWrapper .item', function(){
    alert('Hello');
    });
});
```

Comment: Не сработало. Возможно ли из-за того, что для .extendWrapper задано свойство: tabindex = -1 ?

Comment: Спасибо - проблема была в Ошибке в общем коде js